# Error is .htaccess - Redirects not working and its very strange

Tags: apache, .htaccess

My site has just recently launched a bunch of new product pages, replacing the old ones.

Here is an example of a redirect I want. One going from the old page...redirecting to the new page. I checked Google webmaster and said that there was a not found error for the second link.

```
Redirect 301 /it-infrastructure.html http://www.example.com/managed-enterprise-services.html

Redirect 301 /it-infrastructure http://www.example.com/managed-enterprise-services.html
```

So the .html one is redirecting fine...but the one without the .html extension is not. BUT...what's strange is that I have a bunch of redirects from the past that don't use the html ext and work fine, such as:

```
Redirect 301 /broadsoft-web-portal http://www.example.com/broadsoft-web-portal.html
```

and

```
Redirect 301 /business-voip http://www.example.com/business-voip.html
```

Anyone have any idea why this isn't working?

Comment: Is there a reason you have spaces between the `//` and `www` in your last two Redirect lines?

Answer (score 0):

Add to your .htaccess this line

```
Options -MultiViews
```